# php - how to set dynamic base_url codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, config, codeigniter-3, base-url

I need to access my website with dynamic base_url. I use codeigniter 3.
I've try to set with this 
`$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';`

or

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com';
```

then i access my website with `www.example.com`

but i get error `This site can’t be reached www.example.com’s server DNS address could not be found. ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

How can I fix this error? So I can access this web dynamically.

Comment: its not a coding issue its a registration - DNS - hosting one.

Comment: @Dagon thx for the answer. So it means I have to register the DNS-hosting with 'www'? not only 'example.com' ?

Comment: how is this site hosted?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using localhost, it wouldn't be possible. What i mean is it will be accessible through that name but only in your computer.

Having it in a hosting site gives it it's own DNS name so no problem for it.

But having it through the local host, giving it it's own name would need a DNS and possibly port forwarding if you want to make it global.

Comment: Hello in other words: is it possible to have a local apache with codeigniter 4 accessible simultaneously from local computers and from remote ones?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the base url in this way

```
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .=   str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Comment: i've set the base url as your recommendation, but This site still can’t be reached

Comment: This may be issue in DNS - hosting

Comment: yup it's clearly working, but error when i access with www.example.com, but if i go with example.com it's ok

Comment: DNS - hosting name may be issue